# libGDX: Implementing AI on a sidescroller

Tags: java, libgdx, artificial-intelligence, path-finding

I'm working on a 2D sidescroller game.

**Description:**

Im using libGDX and the AI extension. The game will be released on android (the AI should not be heavy resurce consuming). My terrain is not grid based, it's a procedural generated polygonal height map (without caves).
[image]

There are 3 types of enemies (NPC) - near-, distance- (bullets) and combined-combat.

Entities have 3 ways to move - left, right and jump. Allso some can hover over the ground like on the picture. I tougth to make nodes with an y offset from the terrain should work but if a player jumps, a near-combat enemy couldn't have a path (I didn't test it but i assume it).

I seen many examples on grid based games but non for my scenario.

Excuse my less knowlege, I just jumed in AI devolepment a few days ago.

**Questions:**

- Is the AI (from libGDX) compatible with an (almost) infinite world?
- How should I setup nodes?
- Can the AI be used to calculate bullet directions to hit a player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I do not know libGDX but if you want to have an infinite world you have to program it. That means you generate the terrain randomly and destroy it in the memory if it is not needed any more. If you want infinitely go to the left and the right you have to store efficiently your world on your hard drive if the memory is full. For your polygons, you just have to store the nodes and some numbers as references to surrounding elements if you want to go back with your avatar.

Second, because your game is two-dimensional the possible paths are that simple that you need no path finding algorithms. So you do not need nodes or things like that. What you need is something like hit-boxes so that your enemies know when they hit each other. The AI needs only to know if your avatar is left or right and if it is reachable directly. That are simple geometry calculations. If it is possible to jump over other enemies it is as if they can go through them for the path.

Finally, the bullet direction is calculated simply with linear algebra to get the direct line from your avatar to your enemy. You need only to calculate if it intersects with other enemies or the terrain to know if your avatar can be hit.

The only AI aspect here is to determine the behaviour of the enemies. That can be done with a [state machine](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/finite-state-machines-theory-and-implementation--gamedev-11867), where the enemies have states like `aiming`, `waiting`, `following` or `shooting`. Depending on how far away your avatar is or how reachable it is the states change.